# Minix3 read only issue

Tags: minix

I would just like to know is there a way you can overwrite the `main.c` file in the kernel folder (dir `/usr/src/kernel/main.c`) in MINIX 3. I want to change some code in the file (I know the risks involved) but the problem is I can't save it. I've tried logging in as `bin` and `root` and still the same issue.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within the fact that you may not have installed MINIX 3 and that you are running it from the ISO or CD-ROM. That is why you cannot write the file, as you cannot write to an ISO or CD-ROM.

Follow this link to install in on a hard disc or virtual drive:
[MINIX 3 install guide](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/DoingInstallation#RunningSetup)